# gulp wiredep does not load bower dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview, gulp, wiredep

i have a project on `Angularjs` which covered by unit tests with help of `bower` and `jasmine`. Every thing worked fine until I added a new module (angular-treeview). Module works fine in browser but not in `Phantomjs` while testing. The js is missing by some reason. Here is my gulp task for test :

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wiredep = require('wiredep');
var karmaServer = require('karma').Server;

/**
 * Run the unit tests
 */
gulp.task('test', ['templates'], function() {
    var bowerDeps = wiredep({
        directory: 'src/bower_components',
        exclude: [],
        dependencies: true,
        devDependencies: true
    });
    bowerDeps.js.unshift('src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');

    var testFiles = bowerDeps.js.concat([
        'src/app/app.js', // loading the module first to make Karma avoid nomod-errors
        'src/{app,components}/**/*.js',
        '.tmp/templates/*.js', // HTML-templates converted to JS for directives/etc
        'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ]);

    new karmaServer({
        files: testFiles,
        singleRun: false,
        autoWatch: true,
        configFile: __dirname + '/../test/karma.conf.js'
    }).start();
});
```

`angular-treeview` is in `src/bower_components` but is still missing.

Any ideas?